# Razor: Getting previous/next object properties in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach

I don't know if this is even possible in any meaningful way, but I will try and ask here since I can't seem to find anything about it in google.

I have a "foreach" loop in a cshtml view, where I want to display some content in a slider. In that slider, not only is there arrow's shown, but the names of the next and previous slide is also shown next to the arrow's.

It looks something like this:

```
@foreach (var stop in Model.Accomodations)
{
    <div class="slider controls-above two-column">
        @foreach (var hotel in stop.Hotel_Options)
        {
                <div class="names">
                    <span class="prev">@* previous slides name *@</span>
                    <span class="current">@* Current slides name*@</span>
                    <span class="next">@* Next slides name *@</span>
                </div>       
        }
    </div>
}
```

I have removed some HTML for clarity.

So my question is, is it possible for the inner foreach loop, to get the name's of the previous and next item, relative to the current item it is iterating?
Put into other words: A list of hotel's is displayed in a slider, is it possible to get the name of the next or previous hotel from the hotel the loop is currently looking at?

(Or should I go for a Javascript based solution?)

**EDIT**
Based on feedback I fixed it like so:

```
@foreach (var stop in Model.Accomodations)
{
    <div class="slider controls-above two-column">
        @for (int i = 0; i < stop.Hotel_Options.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div>
                <div class="names">
                    <span class="prev">
                        @{var previousHotel = stop.Hotel_Options.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1);}
                        @if (previousHotel != null)
                        {
                            @previousHotel.Name
                        }
                    </span>
                    <span class="current">@stop.Hotel_Options.ElementAt(i).Name</span>
                    <span class="next">
                        @{var nextHotel = stop.Hotel_Options.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);}
                        @if (nextHotel != null)
                        {
                            @nextHotel.Name
                        }
                    </span>
                </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a `for` loop?

Comment: Not in particular.. I mostly settle on "foreach" but if a "for" loop can accomplish it easier then why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Model.Accomodations`  is an array you could just use a `for loop` and use `[i-1]` and `[i+1]` to get the  previous and next data.

just add an `if` to check if you are at the first or last element.

Comment: Thanks, I used your example as inspiration for a solution. I have updated my original post with the final code.